# Mathematica - Problem with creating symbolic XML

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In a mathematica application I have an OO-System object which represents a cuboid as follows:

```
 In[27]:= oscg@getItem[11]@getObject[]

 Out[27]= {"GE", {"CB", {{3., 0., 3.}, 0.9}}, {0.3}}
```

I transfer this object to Xml with the following method:

```
 In[28]:= oscg@getItem[11]@toXml[]

 Out[28]= XMLElement["cuboid", {"point" -> "{3., 0., 3.}", 
  "diameter" -> "9
  --
  10", "hue" -> "0.3"}, {}]
```

I would have expected here:

```
 XMLElement["cuboid", {"point" -> "{3., 0., 3.}", "diameter" -> "0.9", "hue" -> "0.3"}, {}]
```

The method code is as follows:

```
 toXml[]:= Module[
{ret,
p=getPoint[] + getColref[]@absPoint[getMe[]], 
d=getDiameter[],
h=getHue[]},
ret=XMLElement["cuboid",{"point"->ToString[p], "diameter"->ToString[d], 
    "hue"->ToString[h]}, {}];
ret
];
```

The problem is that 0.9 becomes 9 -- 10.

I thought about a format issue but hue is nicely output as 0.3. ( The problem becomes critical in the stage where the Xml is read and parsed back to object creation code. )

#### Question:

#### Could it nevertheless be a format, display issue? ( A topic I am not very familiar with in Mathematica. ) Any ideas, on how to attack this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diameter is likely stored as a rational:

```
 In[1]:= ToString[9/10]
Out[1]:= 9
         --
         10
```

Notice that two end-of-line codes are needed to print that fraction as a string.

Try `ToString[N@d]`, `ToString[N@h]`, etc. in `toXml[]`. You could also use `ToString[d,InputForm]` to get `9/10`.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you very much. I generated a series of cubes by calculating points and diameters. That's where Mathematica must have stored the number as a Fraction.

Comment: Still, it's and odd way to output a fraction as Xml. But I suppose it's how it should be.